# Rerun JavaScript on successful ajax call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a delete button with the remote: true option set:

```
# _categories.html.erb
<%= link_to 'Destroy', category, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, remote: true %>
```

My destroy method uses json:

```
# categories_controller.rb
  def destroy
    @category = Admin::Category.find(params[:id])
    @category.destroy
    save_to_history("The category \"#{@category.name}\" has been destroyed", current_user.id)

    respond_to do |format|
      # You can't retrieve the @categories before attempting to delete one. 
      @categories = Admin::Category.all

      format.json
    end
  end
```

and my destroy.json.erb file looks like:

```
#destroy.json.erb
<% self.formats = ["html"] %>
{
  "html":"<%= raw escape_javascript( render :partial => 'categories', :content_type => 'text/html') %>"
}
```

Now my problem is that I have this JavaScript run on page load, and deleting an initial category works as intended... Until the data changes. I need this bellow JavaScript to run again every time the user changes data either by adding a new category or deleting a category. How? Please be kind with your help, I do NOT know JavaScript at all! haha

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>

    $(function(){
      /* delete category */
      $('a[data-remote]').on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr){
        $("#dashboard_categories").html(data.html);
      });
    });

  </script>
```

FULL index.html.erb:

```
# index.html.erb
<% title "Categories" %>

<%= form_for @category, remote: true do |f| %>
  <% if @category.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@category.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this category from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @category.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><%= f.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Category Name' %></td>
      <td><%= f.text_field :color, placeholder: 'Colour' %></td>
      <td><%= f.submit %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br />
<% end %>


<div id="dashboard_categories">
  <%= render partial: 'categories' %>
</div>


<% content_for :javascript do %>
  <script type='text/javascript'>

    $(function(){

      /* new category */
      $('#new_admin_category').on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr){
        $("#dashboard_categories").html(data.html);
      });

      /* delete category */
      $('a[data-remote]').on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr){
        $("#dashboard_categories").html(data.html);
      });
    });

  </script>
<% end %>
```

Comment: even with an updater you will have the case of receiving unexisted categories, so it is a good idea to also protect yourself on server side.

Comment: I agree @fotanus , is there a simple way to expand on the answer I accepted?

Comment: Don't edit it now because would invalidate the existing answer. Just take this in consideration while coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know If I have understand you 100% but looks like you want to add the events after AJAX success?

```
$(function () {
    function InitializeEvents() {
        /* new category */
        $('#new_admin_category').on('ajax:success', function (event, data, status, xhr) {
            $("#dashboard_categories").html(data.html);
            InitializeEvents();
        });

        /* delete category */
        $('a[data-remote]').on('ajax:success', function (event, data, status, xhr) {
            $("#dashboard_categories").html(data.html);
            InitializeEvents();
        });
    }
    InitializeEvents();
});
```

Hope it helps :)