# Javascript within pop-up modal not running

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I get the bellow code to run within the load of a JavaScript pop-up modal box? I'm using facebox. http://defunkt.io/facebox/

```
<% content_for :javascript do %>
  <script type='text/javascript'>

    $(function () {
        function InitializeEvents() {
            /* new category */
            $('#new_admin_category').on('ajax:success', function (event, data, status, xhr) {
                $("#dashboard_categories").html(data.html);
                InitializeEvents();
            });

            /* delete category */
            $('a[data-remote]').on('ajax:success', function (event, data, status, xhr) {
                $("#dashboard_categories").html(data.html);
                InitializeEvents();
            });
        }
        InitializeEvents();
    })();

  </script>
<% end %>
```

If you need some more context to what my code is doing, please see previous question here: [Rerun JavaScript on successful ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541796/rerun-javascript-on-successful-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Really simple actually... I removed it from the head and left it in the body...

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>

    $(function () {
        function InitializeEvents() {
            /* new category */
            $('#new_admin_category').on('ajax:success', function (event, data, status, xhr) {
                $("#dashboard_categories").html(data.html);
                InitializeEvents();
            });

            /* delete category */
            $('a[data-remote]').on('ajax:success', function (event, data, status, xhr) {
                $("#dashboard_categories").html(data.html);
                InitializeEvents();
            });
        }
        InitializeEvents();
    })();

  </script>
```